# Strange notation for a decimal expansion of a transcendental number

Tags: notation, transcendental-numbers, decimal-expansion

I am checking page proofs for one of my papers right now and an editor changed

> $\zeta(3)=1.202$$\ldots$

to:

> $\zeta(3) = 1.202,...,$

I find this latter notation very strange and think it is a mistake.  I want to tell them to change it back, but want to make sure that it's not some strange notation that I've never seen but is indeed legitimate.

Has anyone seen someone write the equivalent of $3.14,...,$ to represent the decimal expansion of a transcendental number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are editors and then there are typesetters, who may not be mathematicians at all. I had some four digit integers such as 1375. In partcular, I had some sextuples of integers, one was $\langle 1,4,3375,0,0,1 \rangle $ with the integers separated by commas. Some overzealous copy person, with more training in English than mathematics, decided that standard English puts commas in numbers in the thousands (true) and changed it to  $\langle 1,4,3,375,0,0,1 \rangle $ which is a disaster, it now has seven integers.

I complained quickly, before giving  back the actual corrected proofs. the mathematical editor (whom I had cc'd) sent a note supporting me and cc'd me in return. So, it all worked out.

My advice is to complain quickly but politely and cc some of the mathematicians involved with this publication.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. There are some other strange changes that appear to be done by someone with no background in math.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple, sounds like it. In my case, there were a number of problems getting the book out, and the (unusual) outcome was farming out final typesetting; this does not happen in a steady, successful journal, for instance, without some calamity. Unless they are all outsourcing typesetting now, I suppose. Anyway, if there are multiple errors, make a list by page number and line number if they have given you line numbers, so that some mathematician reviewing the process can find the errors quickly.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple, in case it matters, $\zeta (3)$ is known to be irrational but not known with any certainty to be transcendental, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant#Ap.C3.A9ry.27s_theorem

Comment: I've written up my long list of comments with line-numbers and sent them to my coauthors.  I'm going to push for a second round of page proofs to try to iron the typos out.

Comment: Also, very funny and interesting comment you made about $\zeta(3)$!  It hadn't occurred to me that it might not be transcendental.  (This only came up in this post, not in the paper!)